# Child height to be 100% of scrollable parent content height

Tags: html, css, height, overflow

Please consider this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eKJAj/

I'm trying to have an absolute positioned div (the red line) to take the whole height of the total height of its (yellow) parent ; not just the parent's visible height.

If you try the fiddle you'll see the red bar doesn't go the whole way down when you scroll the yellow div. Also it can't be bigger than its parent if some blue sections are removed.

html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section2"></div>
    <div class="section2"></div>
    <div class="section2"></div>
    <div class="section2"></div>
    <div class="section2"></div>
    <div class="section"></div>
</div>

<input type="button" value="hide" onclick="$('.section2').slideUp(400)" />
<input type="button" value="show" onclick="$('.section2').slideDown(400)" />
```

css:

```
.parent{
    position:relative;
    width:100%; max-height:300px;
    background-color:yellow;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

.bar{
    position:absolute; left:50px;
    width:1px; height:100%;
    background-color:red;
}

.section, .section2{
    width:100%; height:70px;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

I have been trying a few options for the blue bar such as `top:0px; botom:0px` or `position:relative; margin-left:50px` and even made an attemps with floating the red line, to no avail.

If possible I'd rather keep it CSS only. Any hint much appreciated!!

Comment: See if this is ok with you http://jsfiddle.net/eKJAj/14/
although i am not specialist in HTML

Comment: No sorry, it looks like you have just made the section smaller so the parent div doesn't have to scroll. Unfortunately there can be many section inside the parent div so it has to scroll. Thanks though!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One solution is to wrap your `.parent` in a(nother) container.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKJAj/21/).

Set your `.parent`'s container to have the `max-height` and `overflow-y` instead:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- parent in here -->
</div>

.container {
    max-height:300px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
.parent{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

The reason it's not working in your example is because you're setting the maximum height to 300px. The 100% height `.bar` is then assuming a height of 300px. With this workaround, your `.parent` divider doesn't have a 300px height limit, but the outer `.container` does instead.

Comment: I would be adding the `.container` inside the `.parent` but that makes very little difference.

Comment: This is great! Am I wrong in thinking adding a wrapper seems to solve a lot of common CSS problems? I will keep this in mind next time! Thanks ever so much