# CSS overlay on scrollable DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a class `overlay`. The purpose is that I can add it to any div to create an overlay while loading data. It works perfectly except on `divs` where the content can overflow.

**HMTL**

```
<div id="myDiv" >
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div id="innerDiv"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #888888;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 50px;
}
```

Here is the example on
**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8z842871/)**. Scroll down in the box and you will see the problem.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405982/set-width-of-inner-div-on-scrollable-element-to-100-of-scrollable-width

Comment: oh, nope. It's probably this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15243053/child-height-to-be-100-of-scrollable-parent-content-height

Answer (score 1):

Without any JavaScript you will have to pass the `height` of the `innerDiv` to `.overlay` css.

http://jsfiddle.net/urahara/8z842871/3/

```
.overlay {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #888888;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    height:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

With jQuery you can do it dynamically:

http://jsfiddle.net/urahara/8z842871/5/

`$('.overlay').css('height', $('#innerDiv').height());`

Cheers!